AttributeError: 'identity_trans' object has no attribute 'dataspace_is_numerical'
I am trying to create a histogram using ggplot, this is my code:
data = pd.read_csv('Weather_not_tidy.csv')
data = data.rename(columns={'Temp2009': '2009', 'Temp2010': '2010'})

tidyData = pd.melt(data2, value_vars=['2009', "2010"], id_vars=['month', 'day', 'hour_of_day'],
                   var_name='year', value_name='temperature')
tidyData

 month day hour_of_day  year  temperature
0   Jan 1   12  2009    -0.9
1   Jan 2   12  2009    -2.2
2   Jan 3   12  2009    4.2
3   Jan 4   12  2009    -4.7
4   Jan 5   12  2009    -7.8
... ... ... ... ... ...
725 Dec 27  12  2010    -6.8
726 Dec 28  12  2010    -11.0
727 Dec 29  12  2010    -10.6
728 Dec 30  12  2010    -3.0
729 Dec 31  12  2010    -2.7
730 rows × 5 columns

plot = (
    ggplot(tidyData, aes(x='temperature', fill='year'))
    + geom_histogram(data=tidyData.loc[tidyData['year']=='2009'], alpha=0.6, bins=10)
)
plot

and I keep getting this error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/MVE080/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:711, in PlainTextFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    704 stream = StringIO()
    705 printer = pretty.RepresentationPrinter(stream, self.verbose,
    706     self.max_width, self.newline,
    707     max_seq_length=self.max_seq_length,
    708     singleton_pprinters=self.singleton_printers,
    709     type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    710     deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 711 printer.pretty(obj)
    712 printer.flush()
    713 return stream.getvalue()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/MVE080/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py:419, in RepresentationPrinter.pretty(self, obj)
    408                         return meth(obj, self, cycle)
    409                 if (
    410                     cls is not object
    411                     # check if cls defines __repr__
   (...)
    417                     and callable(_safe_getattr(cls, "__repr__", None))
    418                 ):
--> 419                     return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    421     return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    422 finally:
...
     86 return (
---> 87     trans.dataspace_is_numerical and tname not in linear_transforms
     88 )

AttributeError: 'identity_trans' object has no attribute 'dataspace_is_numerical'

I have access to a correct solution to this exercise and it still gives me the exact same error!
I am using vscode on Ubuntu, Python 3.11.10 and am using a conda environment with the following dependencies:
name: MVE080
dependencies:
  - python=3.11
  - plotnine=0.12
  - numpy=1.26
  - pandas=2.1
  - pip=23.1
  - pip:
    - geopandas

I was expecting to see a histogram with temperature from -10 to 10 on the x axis and the count on the y axis! :(

You need to upgrade to a recent version of plotnine.

This fixed it, thank you!

I don't think you posted enough info to solve this problem,
but that error means that somewhere in the code there is something called identity_trans and that somewhere in the code you are trying to access an attribute of that object that is not an attribute of that object.
I would look for identity_trans in the code and see where it's trying to reference dataspace_is_numerical as a start.
You posted some of your code but you need to show the part of the code that has dataspace_is_numerical in it for us to really help you.
Edit based on the log I think the problem is probably with pretty.py which is not your program but something that you installed to run with your program I think, perhaps reinstalling that could help.

I don't have dataspace_is_numerical anywhere in my code. I will update the question with a more complete error log.
